# What's the difference between bower bootstrap-sass and bootstrap-sass-official

Tags: bower, bootstrap-sass

What is the difference between `bootstrap-sass` and `bootstrap-sass-official` in the [bower registry](http://bower.io)?

[The bower registry](http://bower.io) lists both, although they both point to https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bootstrap-sass-official used to place source files under

bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/...

now that its just pointing at bootstrap-sass, the paths are all different

ie. installing bootstrap-sass-official now means you have to reference

bootstrap-sass/assets

instead of

bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets

(if you never used the OLD bootstrap-sass-official - that won't affect you)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the update meta and ownership of both, I'd say, nothing. No diff.